# Creating DPDT Solid State Relay with FETs

Tags: mosfet, solid-state-relay, dpdt

I feel like this should be a very simple question but so far I have not found a solution. My goal is to make the following DPDT relay circuit using MOSFETs:

[image]

The goal is to connect INX to OUTX or OUTY and INY to OUTY or OUTX depending on the state of an input signal (I have two data lines available for the switch control). Normally I would use a mechanical relay but due to the nature of my project this really won't work, I need a solid-state option. DPDT solid-state relays are very difficult to come by, and any I have found cannot be connected to work in the way shown in the image.

I was looking at using two enhancement mode and two depletion mode N-channel MOSFETs, but since a FET needs a G-S voltage to switch on I would not be able to simply pass the data signals straight through the FETs as they need to be isolated from ground.

So how might one construct a DPDT solid state relay entirely out of MOSFETs that would allow them to swap the two outputs (connecting INX to OUTY and INY to OUTX, or vice versa)?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I had been looking at using bilateral switches but most of them can only handle about 30mA. These particular data lines can carry up to 200mA, so I'm looking for a ~500mA solution (hence using discrete FETs).

EDIT 2: I was looking at these: http://download.siliconexpert.com/pdfs/2014/7/28/1/10/31/351/aro_/manual/semi_eng_ge2a_aqw21_e.pdf

My thought was to connect them as follows (please pardon the crudity of the drawing, it had to be done in MS Paint, and I didn't want to put detail of the FETs and all in it. Just know that each pair of wires on the output are effectively connected to a switch:

[image]

Comment: Is that not basically an H-Bridge?

Comment: Not quite. An H-bridge simply switches direction of current through the load. I want to be able to swap data lines based on the "position" of the "switch"

Comment: ^this. You can search for ready made H bridges, they usually include a drive circuit for the high side mos. If you just wanna switch some signals what you are searching for is passgates.

Comment: So, connect your one data line to the top and one data line to the bottom of the H-Bridge.  Your outputs are where the motor would go.

Comment: I would still need the G-S voltage to switch the FETs, which means the return of my control signal would have to be connected to  the data lines, no?

Comment: Otherwise, that's what I was originally thinking of doing, but didn't think it could be done in this particular application

Comment: Will this do: [DG9415 Dual 2x1 Multiplexer](http://www.vishay.com/docs/71766/dg9414.pdf) ... Just saw the current requirement. I guess not.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately not. The current handling is really what's killing me now.

Comment: I have also looked at opto-relays, like using two of these: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/205/Lcc110-444.pdf . While the current rating is a bit higher, it's still not quite where it needs to be.

Comment: I found this [DPST SSR](http://cotorelay.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/c247s_c347s_mosfet_relay_datasheet.pdf) which is rated for 1A. 150 mΩ. So you would need two, and use an inverter in front of the second IC's control lead.  [$8.09 @ in singles](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/C347S/306-1308-ND/3961373), $4.72 in thousands.

Comment: Thanks @tcrosley! I like that the on-resistance is significantly lower than the ones I was looking at (http://download.siliconexpert.com/pdfs/2014/7/28/1/19/40/973/aro_/manual/semi_eng_gu2a_aqw21.pdf). I'm not sure if the extra cost is worth it, but it definitely gives me a great place to start

Comment: Why can't you use a mechanical relay?  Perhaps a latching relay would work?

Comment: I have opted out of using a mechanical relay for the following reasons: 1) They tend to be big and bulky, which really won't fit well on the board I'm designing. 2) The electro-magnetic field generated by the coil can cause interference on the data lines which could, in theory, skew the data. 3) The noise from the contacts can affect the signal quality. 4) Having mechanical parts means there's more that can go wrong, and that it's more likely to go wrong. Basically I'm choosing a solid-state option for the same reason that any people who select a SSR over a mechanical relay do.

Comment: I made my earlier comment into an answer in case you end up using it.

Comment: Thanks very much @tcrosley. I think I even settled on this solution even before you made the comment. I +1'd your answer though, and if I end up doing it I will still accept yours, as it agrees with what I landed on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the simplest option: Instead of a "Solid-State Relay" like I kept asking for, what I think I was actually looking for was a DPDT analog switch like the NLAS44599 (Datasheet: http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NLAS44599-D.PDF). The functional diagram looks like this:

[image: DPDT Analog Switch]

I hope this might help someone in the future who's looking for the same thing I was. Sure, it's a 16-pin device, but it does exactly what I need it to.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine multiple SSRs to do this. Two form B and two form A will give you a DPDT SSR. Cost would be fairly high (about $20 in singles) but this is really a weird set of requirements. Switching will be slow.

For example, two LCB710 and two CLA230 (IXYS) would handle 700mA.

You could also buy PV optoisolators and use them to drive back-to-back MOSFETs for each switch. Since the former come in pairs you'd end up with 8 parts (plus maybe 4 resistors). Again, slow switching.

Edit: Since you imply in the comment below that there is no requirement for power-off normally closed, the simplest method is probably to use two dual form A SSRs such as TLP222A-2.

Again you could use dual MOSFETs and PV drivers, but I don't see much point in that since the current requirements (and presumably your voltage requirements) are met by common parts.

[image]

Comment: I agree, this is a very weird set of requirements, and I appreciate your help. I was hoping to keep the part count as low as possible to avoid significant switching time differences between chips. Otherwise I would use 4 SPST SSRs which are very cheap and plentiful. If I must use more than one or two devices, then I must. I was just hoping there would be a way to do this with, say, 4 discrete transistors

Comment: Okay, you mentioned depletion mode which I took to likely be a requirement that it conduct with no power. Pls. see edit.

Comment: I mentioned depletion mode in case I could use my two control lines in a bipolar way (switch "direction" of the current to switch on a different relay "contact"). It's funny you should show the opto-relay above, I was just looking at this: http://download.siliconexpert.com/pdfs/2014/7/28/1/10/31/351/aro_/manual/semi_eng_ge2a_aqw21_e.pdf

Comment: I have made an edit to my initial post. What I added allows the use of only two devices, and though it's still not ideal it may still work.

Answer (score 1):

As the OP said, it is very difficult to find DPDT SSR (solid state relays). But there are a some ways around this; use two SPDT relays, like [this one](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/205/Lcc110-444.pdf), or use one DPST-NO and one DPST-NC as proposed in another answer, or finally, use two DPST, with an inverter in front of the control for the second relay.

For this particular application, the need to handle relatively high currents (at least 500 mA) with a low on-resistance weere the critical specifications.

I found this [DPST C347S SSR](http://cotorelay.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/c247s_c347s_mosfet_relay_datasheet.pdf) which is rated for 1A. 150 mΩ. So you would need two, and use an inverter in front of the second IC's control lead. [$8.09 @ in singles](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/C347S/306-1308-ND/3961373), $4.72 in thousands.

[image]

Comment: I think you and I are on the same track. This sounds very much like what I've done in the latest edit of my original post =)

Answer (score 0):

this is the digital equiv of an h circuit, fwd rev motor drivers. try the tlp222 optical isolated fet driver, and if the current demands are really high follow the design and use opto isolators to keep one side that is on from inverting the side that is off and reverse biasing the fets. some diodes might come in handy during development

Comment: I suggest you read some of the comments, this is not quite the same as an H-bridge.

Comment: sorry h bridge. out of pete's French roast. It is not too much different. what the objective here, is to make a bidirectional on off switch. right?

Comment: Nope, not at all. Please read my initial post and the comments.

Comment: well good luck, use gloves and goggles, the one I have on my boat works at 40 amps 36 volts.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as follows:

Use a pair of photovoltaic optos to generate an isolated voltage source.

Connect enough N-channel MOSFETs (back-to-back in pairs) as you need. That would be 4 pairs.

Finally, use opto-isolators to drive the gates of the MOSFETs. You want to use the optos in a tptem-pole configuration so as to minimize the current from the photovoltaic source.

I'll draw up a quick schematic when I get in front of a computer.

This gives you the ability to switch very quickly and handle as much current as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it for a bms using discrete FETs [image]

I've looked at analog switches as well, but the issues I seem to run into is the difficultly in managing the supply and common mode voltages